# How to resolve 'Integrity constraint violation', 'a foreign key constraint fails' in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-key-relationship

$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE my_data_and_attribute
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_44E5AE29CAA2B25 FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFEREN  
  CES my_data (id)':                                                

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update   
  a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`symfony`.`#sql-3e2_186`, CONSTR  
  AINT `FK_44E5AE29CAA2B25` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `my_data` (`id`))
```

An error has occurred.
I had recently replace data from other database that had execute update command.
So, I think the cause of error is that I had done replace data.
(I don't know what it may cause from completely different something.)

And I also try to change relationship from phpMyAdmin.
But it failed like this.

```
Error

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `my_data_and_attribute` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `data_id` ) REFERENCES `symfony`.`my_data` (
`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`symfony`.`#sql-3e9_1ea`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-3e9_1ea_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `my_data` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I can't understand this error messages.
Where should I check for?

---

symfony.my_data

```
#   Column  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default     Extra         
1   id      int(11)                         No      None        AUTO_INCREMENT
// ...

Indexes:
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes     No      id      517         A
```

symfony.my_data_and_attribute

```
#   Column          Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra
1   data_id         int(11)                         No      None    
2   attribute_id    int(11)                         No      None    

INDEXES
Keyname         Type    Unique  Packed  Column      Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY         BTREE   Yes     No      data_id     483         A       
                                        attribute_id483         A   
data_id         BTREE   No      No      data_id     483         A       
attribute_id    BTREE   No      No      attribute_id37          A
```

Relation view

```
Column      Internal relation   Foreign key constraint (INNODB)
data_id                                                         // <- I can not set value this point.
attribute_id                    `symfony`.`my_attribute`.`id`   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Comment: foreign key in table my_data_and_attribute

Answer (score 0):

I would probably need both create table statement to answer correctly, but it's very likely that my_data_and_attribute.data_id is not exactly the same field type than my_data.id .
It can happen for instance if one of the field is UNSIGNED and the other is not or if the fields are not both the same size.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I added some detail. Both field type is 'int(11)'. I do not understand your advice point?

Comment: Can you post the result of a "show create table my_data" and "show create table my_data_and_attribute" ? It'll be easier to read and understand

Comment: Try to do it manually or through phpmyadmin and copy/paste the query for migrations, later.